# How can I manage shared App Engine code with Git between iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, git, google-app-engine, git-submodules

My team is in the planning stages for an app that will span multiple platforms, and I am trying to figure out how to handle its version control. There will be:

- an iOS app (has its own Git repo, on GitHub)
- an Android app (has its own Git repo, on GitHub)
- a Google App Engine backend for the iOS and Android app

How can I Git, or some other tool like [Repo](http://source.android.com/source/developing.html), so both iOS and Android can easily share the same App Engine code?
Should I use subtrees? Or submodules?

All three modules are built by gradle, and both mobile apps have a dependency on the app engine backend (for Cloud Endpoints).

Note: I want to take advantage of the [Android Studio built-in App Engine functionality](https://cloud.google.com/mobile/).